# What is the full space of parametrically polymorphic functions (not ad hoc polymorphic) operations in programming languages?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, parametric-polymorphism, type-theory, adhoc-polymorphism

On page 349 paragraph 5 of [*A Theory of Type Polymorphism in Programming*](https://www.pure.ed.ac.uk/ws/files/15143545/1_s2.0_0022000078900144_main.pdf), Milner says,

> For us, the polymorphism present in a program is a natural outgrowth
> of the primitive polymorphic operators which appear to exist in every
> programming language; such operators are assignment, function
> application, pairing and tupling, and list-processing operators.

Does this description define the full set of parametrically polymorphic functions (When we extend list processing operators to mean operators on all recursive data types)? (`+`, `*`, ... need to be defined in an ad hoc style with different underlying implementations for each type they handle). Also, is there some kind of formal pattern that separates a parametrically polymorphic function from one that has to be defined with overloading (ad hoc)?

Comment: Most PLs let you define your own polymorphic functions, so this list is plainly not the full list.

Comment: Edited my question. I think you missed the point partially because of my poor description. I mean to ask whether there are parametrically polymorphic functions outside of assignment, function application, pairing and tupling, and list-processing operators (including trees and other recursive data stuctures). Obviously there are a ton of functions you can make to do list processing.

Comment: @ConorQuinn, I think Milner's point is that polymorphism "in the large" grows out of polymorphism "in the small". I don't think he's talking about deep theory in that statement, though he surely knew that theory very well indeed.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this description define the full set of parametrically polymorphic functions?

Certainly not. Church teaches us that there is an infinitely rich collection of parametrically polymorphic functions. For example:

```
type Nat = forall a. (a -> a) -> a -> a

zero :: Nat
zero s z = z

succ :: Nat -> Nat
succ n s z = s (n s z)

one, two, three :: Nat
one = succ zero
two = succ one
three = succ two
```

All of `zero`, `one`, `two`, and `three` are parametrically polymorphic functions; and they are all distinct in that there are arguments we can apply them to that give different results for each. And this is just the [Church encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding) of one of the simplest recursive data types. The encodings of other data types also give rise to an incredibly complex family of parametrically polymorphic functions of other types... and there are parametrically polymorphic functions which do not correspond to the Church encoding of *any* data type.

Trying to write down a list of all parametrically polymorphic functions would be a hopeless task indeed, akin (by the [Curry-Howard isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence)) to writing down a list of all mathematical truths!

> Also, is there some kind of formal pattern that separates a parametrically polymorphic function from one that has to be defined with overloading (ad hoc)?

Not really. The dictionary-passing implementation of typeclasses in GHC is a witness that any definition that relies on ad-hoc polymorphism can be converted to use parametric polymorphism instead in a systematic, mechanical way.

Comment: I think the general case of list processing operators is operations on recursive datatypes. I would humbly argue that this example falls into that category.

Comment: @ConorQuinn No, there is no recursive type in the code snippet here!

Comment: @ConorQuinn ...and, more to the point, this was just an example. As mentioned in the answer, there are inhabited types which are neither recursive types nor the encoding of recursive types.